# Regex that exclude specific pattern of ip

Tags: javascript

I am filtering specific ip address via regex. For example,
all the ip address containing 1 in the last octet i.e. XXX.XXX.XXX.1 should be excluded but not 11 or 123 or 125. Sample example:

the regex should discard
192.168.1.1
192.168.20.1
192.168.30.1
but should not discard
192.168.1.101
192.168.20.103
I have tried the regex as :
`^(?!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.[^\1]).*$`
but could not exclude as expected.

Any help is appreciated !!!

Answer (score 3):

When matching the final octet, use `(?:1\d+|[02-9]\d*)$` - either match a 1 which is followed by other digits, or match something which *isn't* a 1, possibly followed by other digits:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}\.(?:1\d+|[02-9]\d{0,2})$
```

https://regex101.com/r/gB5c6z/1

Another option, with negative lookahead:

[`^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}\.(?!1$)\d{1,3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/gB5c6z/2)

Comment: I'd be more specific, and at the end, use `{1,2}` and `{0,2}` instead of `+` and `*`, respectively...

Answer (score 1):

considering given format and ip's will be valid you can use endsWith

```js
let ips = [`192.168.1.1`, `192.168.20.1`, `192.168.30.1`, `192.168.1.101`, `192.168.20.103`]

let checker = (str) => !str.endsWith(`.1`)

ips.forEach(v => console.log(checker(v)))
```

Comment: This should be used together with a regex-based syntax-check, but you're right.